# how to read specific values using Json to dict?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary

```
                "Instances": [{
                    "nlu_classification": {
                        "Domain": "UDE",
                        "Intention": "Unspecified"
                    },
                    "nlu_interpretation_index": 1,
                    "nlu_slot_details": {
                        "Name": {
                            "literal": "ConnectedDrive"
                        },
                        "Search-phrase": {
                            "literal": "connecteddrive"
                        }
                    },
                    "interpretation_confidence": 5484
                }],
                "type": "nlu_results",
                "api_version": "1.0"
            }],
            "nlps_version": "nlps(z):6.1.100.12.2-B359;Version: nlps-base-Zeppelin-6.1.100-B124-GMT20151130193521;"
        }
    },
    "final_response": 1,
    "prompt": "",
    "result_format": "appserver_post_results"
}
```

I am getting the above code as a reply from the server. I am storing those result in the variable NLU_RESULT. later I am using json_loads to convert that json_format into dict and to check for the specific value within it as below.

```
parsed_json = json.loads(NLU_RESULT)
print(parsed_json["Instances"]["nlu_classification"]["Domain"]).
```

when I use the above code. Its not printing the value of Domain. Can someone tell me what is the mistake here ?

Comment: The posted json doesn't parse.

Comment: @suni it doesn't parse because it's (well, what you posted here at least) *not* valid JSON.

Comment: Notice that the value for the key "Instances" is a list not a dict, so you can't access like `parsed_json["Instances"]["nlu_classification"]` but this may work `parsed_json["Instances"][0]["nlu_classification"]`

Comment: @suni garbage in, garbage out

Comment: I am getting the error as : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\Parsing_throug_folder_DEU.py", line 161, in <module>
    print(parsed_json["Instances"][0]["nlu_classification"])
KeyError: 'Instances'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE 
it should be something like

```
parsed['appserver_results']['payload']['actions'][0]['Instances'][0]['nlu_classification']['Domain']
```

the json you posted has instances as an array
so it should be something like

```
print(parsed_json["Instances"][0]["nlu_classification"]["Domain"])
```

also the json is a bit broken and contains some array closing without the array

Comment: thanks !! but I am getting the error as : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\Parsing_throug_folder_DEU.py", line 161, in <module>
    print(parsed_json["Instances"][0]["nlu_classification"]["Domain"])
KeyError: 'Instances'

Comment: can you supply a valid json output?

Comment: I updated my question. I hope that is what you were asking for !! I am interested only in reading the values of Domain, intention : "Instances": [{
         "nlu_classification": {
          "Domain": "UDE",
          "Intention": "Unspecified"
         },
         "nlu_interpretation_index": 1,
         "nlu_slot_details": {
          "Name": {
           "literal": "ConnectedDrive"

Comment: I updated my answer with regards to the complete json

Comment: i can help you in the chat

Comment: I have less reputation to do that. can we chat in gmail ?

Comment: you should you bpython, ipython or even the regular python repl to simply wonder around the tree. I would suggest using ipython as it can autocomplete